# How do you add users and additional details to a user node in the Database every time they're registered?

Tags: javascript, php, database, firebase

I've tried to create the code by using what I've found online about adding additional details to a user node, but I've come up without a clear cut and definite solution. I can't make heads or tails with Google searches and other such things, but I only found a depreciated solution that's not supported and does not work with the current version of Firebase. So far, here's what I've come up with:

```
(function(){
  var ref = new firebase.database();
  ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
    if (authData && isNewUser) {
      // save the user's profile into Firebase so we can list users,
      // use them in Security and Firebase Rules, and show profiles
      ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
        provider: authData.provider,
        name: getName(authData)
      });
    }
  });
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    var uiConfig = {
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            // User successfully signed in.
            // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
            // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
            return true;
          },
          uiShown: function() {
            // The widget is rendered.
            // Hide the loader.
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
          }
        },
        // Will use popup for IDP Providers sign-in flow instead of the default, redirect.
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInSuccessUrl: 'map_menu.php',
        signInOptions: [
          firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
        // Terms of service url.
        tosUrl: 'map_menu.php',
        // Privacy policy url.
        privacyPolicyUrl: 'map_menu.php'
      };

      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
})()
```

Comment: @Saberton did my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Yes! Thank you. I apologize for not responding immediately, I was busy!

Comment: glad to help, Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a code to get the user data like `uid` as the main child of the user and all other details as sub child nodes of this node in your database.

A Json structure that looks something like this:

```json
{
      "accounts" : {
        "userId value" : {
          "email" : "",
          "userId" : ""
        },
        "userId value" : {
          "email" : "",
          "userId" : ""
        }
      }
```

To save the users' details in this node, just when they are registered, you can add a code like this:

```js
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref().child('accounts').child(uid).set({
  email: user.email,
  userId: uid
})
```